# Modifying a tikzset to accepts more macros

Tags: tikzset

I found the below tikzset on StackExchange and I want to modify it to accept more parameters than just the pipe width, I want to be able to change this `pipe width={(\pipewidth)*4/3}` and the color as well; i.e., `draw=black!70!white!\j!white`. I want the smaller pipe to have different color and different junctions size.

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{every pipe/.code={%
  \pgfmathloop
  \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>20
  \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro\i{\pgfmathcounter}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\j{80-\pgfmathcounter*3}%
    \tikzset{preaction/.expanded={line width=(\pipewidth)*(1-\i*\i/500),
        draw=black!50!white!\j!white}}%
  \repeatpgfmathloop
},
every flange/.style 2 args={insert path={
  let \p1=(#1), \p2=(#2),\n1={atan2(\y2-\y1, \x2-\x1)} in
    [shift={(\p1)}, rotate=\n1, pipe width={(\pipewidth)*4/3}, every pipe] 
      (0.01,0) -- (0.2,0)
}},
flanges/.style={postaction={%
  /utils/exec={
    \@for\pos:=#1\do{%
      \tikzset{decoration/.expanded={markings,
        mark=at position \pos\space with {
          \noexpand\path [pipe width=\pipewidth*4/3, every pipe] (0.01,0) -- (0.2,0);
    }}}}}, 
  decorate}},
pipe width/.code=\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pipewidth{#1},
pipes/.style={
  every pipe,
  postaction={decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={
      \path [every flange={\tikzinputsegmentfirst}{\tikzinputsegmentlast}];
      \path [every flange={\tikzinputsegmentlast}{\tikzinputsegmentfirst}];
    },
    curveto code={
      \path [every flange={\tikzinputsegmentfirst}{\tikzinputsegmentsupporta}];
      \path [every flange={\tikzinputsegmentlast}{\tikzinputsegmentsupportb}];
    }
}, decorate}},
pipe/.style={
  every pipe,
  flanges={0, 1}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\path [pipe width=0.8cm, pipes] (0,6) -- (0,1) arc (180:270:2)--(5,-1);
\path [pipe width=0.1cm, pipes] (0.2,6) -- (0.2,1.15) arc (180:270:2)--(5,-0.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please post a complete, compilable example? That way we don't have to guess which packages you load (yes, that matters) and how you use your keys. Thanks for helping us helping you!

Comment: I did it and included all the details

Comment: You can use handlers `/.style 2 args={<key-val list using #1 and #2>}`, `/.style n args={<n>}{<key-val list using #1 to #n>}`, and `/.style args={<arg pattern>}{<key-val list>}`.